# Not Implemented Error in Django Channels Layers

Tags: python, django, django-channels

I was following the [Django channels tutorial](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/part_2.html#enable-a-channel-layer) to create a simple chat application.
But while trying to check if the channel layer can connect to Redis, I get this Not Implemented Error.

```
>>> async_to_sync(channel_layer.send)('test_channel', {'type': 'hello'})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\Web Development\DJANGO\Channels\venv\lib\site-packages\asgiref\sync.py", line 204, in __call__
    return call_result.result()
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 439, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 391, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "D:\Web Development\DJANGO\Channels\venv\lib\site-packages\asgiref\sync.py", line 270, in main_wrap
    result = await self.awaitable(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Web Development\DJANGO\Channels\venv\lib\site-packages\channels_redis\core.py", line 343, in send
    async with self.connection(index) as connection:
  File "D:\Web Development\DJANGO\Channels\venv\lib\site-packages\channels_redis\core.py", line 902, in __aenter__
    self.conn = await self.pool.pop()
  File "D:\Web Development\DJANGO\Channels\venv\lib\site-packages\channels_redis\core.py", line 93, in pop
    conn = await self.create_conn(loop)
  File "D:\Web Development\DJANGO\Channels\venv\lib\site-packages\channels_redis\core.py", line 79, in create_conn
    return await aioredis.create_redis_pool(**kwargs)
  File "D:\Web Development\DJANGO\Channels\venv\lib\site-packages\aioredis\commands\__init__.py", line 188, in create_redis_pool
    pool = await create_pool(address, db=db,
  File "D:\Web Development\DJANGO\Channels\venv\lib\site-packages\aioredis\pool.py", line 58, in create_pool
    await pool._fill_free(override_min=False)
  File "D:\Web Development\DJANGO\Channels\venv\lib\site-packages\aioredis\pool.py", line 383, in _fill_free
    conn = await self._create_new_connection(self._address)
  File "D:\Web Development\DJANGO\Channels\venv\lib\site-packages\aioredis\connection.py", line 121, in create_connection
    reader, writer = await asyncio.wait_for(open_unix_connection(
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 408, in wait_for
    return await fut
  File "D:\Web Development\DJANGO\Channels\venv\lib\site-packages\aioredis\stream.py", line 39, in open_unix_connection
    transport, _ = await get_event_loop().create_unix_connection(
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 387, in create_unix_connection
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError
```

Channel_Layers configuration:

```
ASGI_APPLICATION = 'justchat.asgi.application'
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            'hosts': [('redis://127.0.0.1, 6379')]
        },
    },
}
```

Redis Server is running:
[Redis Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHbUp.png)

I have been following this tutorial since the start and my code is same as it is there.
What should I do?

Comment: Have you implented those channels ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in the configuration:

```
 'hosts': [('redis://127.0.0.1, 6379')]
```

should be like:

```
 'hosts': [('localhost', 6379)]
```

Comment: Oh! Thank you. That was such a stupid mistake.